# UITextField.inputView suddenly not popping up UIPickerView after working for days

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I'm working on my first app ever (quite a learning experience).  Today after studying and reading and trial/error I was able to programmatically create and fill a UIPickerView and have it pop up when I select the appropriate UITextField.

I have my main `ViewController` with a `UITableView` already setup and populated with some JSON data.  Above the `UITableView` I added a subview (called `FilterView` below) I want to house some controls to filter my `UITableView` (I'm not so sure the subview isn't part of the problem).  After creating my `UIPickerView` in code (didn't use Storyboard) and filling it with some data, and setting my `UITextField` in my subview with the appropriate .inputView (to trigger the `UIPickerView` to appear) I had everything working the way I wanted and was about to move on to setting precedents for filtering my `UITableView.

So here is my layout of my views with textfields in storyboard:
[image]

You'll notice I have my main view (called `View`), a subview with all my controls in it (called `FilterView`), and my `UITableView` below all that.  Then I created my three picker `UIPickerViews` in my `viewDidLoad`, set the DataSource and Delegate and set the inputView to the textfields I wanted:

```
_voltagePickerView =    [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[_voltagePickerView setDataSource: self];
[_voltagePickerView setDelegate: self];
_voltagePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
_voltageFilterField.inputView = _voltagePickerView;

//same for other 3
```

And of course the UIPickerView properties are in my `ViewController.h` file, along with the Outlets for the `UITextField`s:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *rpmPickerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *voltagePickerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *noiseLevelPickerView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *voltageFilterField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *rpmFilterField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *noiseLevelFilterField;
```

All the methods for the PickerView are also setup:

```
// PickerViews //
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if ([pickerView isEqual: _voltagePickerView]) {
        return voltagePickerValues.count;
    }
    else if () {
        //Rest of PickerView rows
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *title;

    if ([pickerView isEqual: _voltagePickerView]) {
        title = [voltagePickerValues objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if {
        //Rest of Picker Views
    }

    else {
        title = nil;
    }

    return title;

}
```

All of this would work fine!  I would run the project, TableView would populate, and I could click on the appropriate TextField in order to show the appropriate PickerView with the correct data populated into them.

Then... The only thing I changed (that I can think of) was changing the PlaceHolderText property of one of my UITextFields... that's it, I may have also lined up the TextFields to look better.  Then I ran the project and the Pickers would not show when I clicked on a TextField.  I checked the Outlets for the TextViews and PickerFields, all the same.  I even deleted the Reference Outlets for the TextViews and recreated them.  Nothing.

I honestly have no clue what happened.  Everything is exactly the same way as it was before with the exception of the PlaceHolderText property of one of the `UITextFields`.

I've cleaned and rebuilt my project, restarted xcode and even my mac, but nothing.

What am I missing??  Sorry for the lengthy post, and thanks so much if you made it this far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting I thought I'd answer in hopes it will help others.

I had to change the hardware settings in the simulator.  I don't know why but the simulator seems to be bugged.

Unchecking `Hardware => Keyboard => Connect Hardware Keyboard` in the simulator fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with dummy titles and it worked for me.

One thing that I added that was missing from your code excerpts was:

```
[self.view addSubview:_voltagePickerView];
```

where self is the view controller.

Comment: Thank you! I had this in my viewDidLoad() at one time but took it out for debugging/trial error. Strangely it worked without it. Maybe a fresh build refactored something?  I will test this as soon as I'm back in front of my project.

Comment: Ok I added `[self.view addSubview:_voltagePickerView];` in my viewDidLoad() after alloc and init the PickerView and setting datasource and delegate.  When I run the project it shows the PickerView (populated) on top of my TableView and SubView  instead of being hidden and popping up when I click my textfield. This was the problem I originally had and removed that line of code. Am I putting it in the right place? Thanks!

Comment: Right after the addsubview line, type:  `[_voltagePickerView setHidden:TRUE];` then, when you click the textfield, in the action method `[_voltagePickerView setHidden:FALSE];`

Comment: I don't think it likes the fact the TextViews are inside a SubView of my main ViewController.  When I tap my textfield it crashes saying: `UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7fd67bd4c2b0> should have parent view controller:<ViewController: 0x7fd67be2b400> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7fd67c0b1a00>'`

This is strange because it worked fine before without having to invoke my addSubView method.  Simply using `_voltagePickerView =    [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];` worked like a charm...

Comment: WEIRD... on a whim I changed the simulator to iPhone 6 and it WORKS like it originally did (no need to manually hide and show the picker).  All the code in the original post works.

Change it back to iphone 5S and it quit working again.  But in the simulator?

Comment: Unchecking `Hardware => Keyboard => Connect Hardware Keyboard`  in the simulator fixed the problem.  Is this a bug in the simulator?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know there were such differences between simulators. I tested on iPhone 5. Also if the answer works, please "accept" it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it technically didn't answer the question.  I had at one point the addSubView in my project during testing but removed it to get the application to work.  It was just a hunch to change simulators.  I'm guessing it is just a bug in the simulator.  Thank you again though, I sincerely appreciate the time you've taken to help me.

Comment: np - feel free to revoke adjusted answer - maybe someone else can chip in. happy coding!